# Copy/Duplicate SonarQube Branch?

Tags: sonarqube

Is it possible to copy/duplicate a SonarQube branch (using the [Branch Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin)) to a new branch? Or would analysis have to be re-run with new branch's name?

Here's an example:

The `master` branch is the main branch of a project. Now let's say version 2.0 of the product is being released. Before version 3.0 code is created and analyzed, we want to spin-off a `release-2.0` long-lived branch from master. What is the most efficient way to do this?

1. Is there an option to duplicate the main branch in SonarQube to a new branch with a new name?
2. Or Would you have to re-perform analysis on the code but specify the `sonar.branch.name` property as `release-2.0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no functionality within SonarQube to duplicate. You must perform analysis with the new branch name to create your long-lived branch.